# Disable Gnome Shell document preview

Tags: gnome, keyboard, libreoffice, shortcuts, usability

I have a password protected LibreOffice Calc file. When I press the SUPER key and type the name it is shown. Now I press enter or click the file and it is opened with some document preview, but this crashes saying that the file can not be found.

The current workaround is:

1. Press the super key
2. Enter the filename
3. Press cursor-left
4. Press the return key
5. Click right on the file
6. Click "open with libreoffice calc" at the bottom of the page

Gnome-do opened the file directly after three steps in the default program, so this is what I would like to have for the gnome-shell finder

How can I disable this preview for all and forever?